# Convert string JSONS records into Dataset

Tags: python, pyspark

I've a file in which JSON like records are present, here is a sample record:

```
{"name": "pim pom",
 "types": "amy \n klim\nshining rock(ABC)\nflying\nchanning",
 "url": "http://doingrock.com",
 "image": "http://static.doingrock.com/rockisland.jpg",
 "pullTime": "PT3AM",
 "rockHeight": "8",
 "dateLive": "2010-10-14",
 "hitTime": "PT8PM",
 "desc": "Amazing view"}
```

Note: it's a single record in one line, showed like this for easy understanding.

I'm trying to read all these records, and convert it into Dataset where I could store all JSONs as class object so that I could access class attributes stored in Dataset for further calculations.

Here is what am doing:

Reading from file

```
    schema = StructType([StructField("name", StringType(), True),
                    StructField("ingredients", StringType(), True),
                    StructField("url", StringType(), True),
                    StructField("images", StringType(), True),
                    StructField("pullTime", StringType(), True),
                    StructField("rockHeight", StringType(), True),
                    StructField("dateLive", StringType(), True),
                    StructField("hitTime", StringType(), True),
                    StructField("desc", StringType(), True)])

    dataset = spark.sparkContext.textFile('D:/pythonwork/FUN/input/*')

   dataDicts = dataset.toDF().select(from_json(dataset, schema).alias("dicts"))
```

It's giving me RDD of JSONs records in string type. Can I create a class like data structure where I could store JSON like string into Class object and create a `dataset<JSONObjects>` ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`read.json()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-json.html). Now each of the json keys will be a column in the dataframe making it easy to do further processing. This will also automatically infer the schema, but if you want to manually specify the schema because for example, the data does not include the `ingredients` column but it is needed in the dataset then do so with `schema()`.

```py
schema = StructType([StructField("name", StringType(), True),
                    StructField("ingredients", StringType(), True),
                    StructField("url", StringType(), True),
                    StructField("images", StringType(), True),
                    StructField("pullTime", StringType(), True),
                    StructField("rockHeight", StringType(), True),
                    StructField("dateLive", StringType(), True),
                    StructField("hitTime", StringType(), True),
                    StructField("desc", StringType(), True)])

df = spark.read.schema(schema).json("/path/to/json-input.json")

df.show()

+-------+-----------+--------------------+------+--------+----------+----------+-------+------------+
|   name|ingredients|                 url|images|pullTime|rockHeight|  dateLive|hitTime|        desc|
+-------+-----------+--------------------+------+--------+----------+----------+-------+------------+
|pim pom|       null|http://doingrock.com|  null|   PT3AM|         8|2010-10-14|  PT8PM|Amazing view|
|pim pom|       null|http://doingrock.com|  null|   PT3AM|         8|2010-10-14|  PT8PM|Amazing view|
+-------+-----------+--------------------+------+--------+----------+----------+-------+------------+
```